# Almost identical ip address, is this the same user…?

Tags: ip-address

i 'm the administrador of a forum and on the admin control panel  i can see the ip assign to the users

i have 3 specific users with the following ip

```
user1:   95.169.240.54 
user2:   95.169.240.177
user3:   95.169.240.220
```

As you can see, the ip is almost the same, and if i look at the site http://whatismyipaddress.com/ i see that they are from the same organization, etc...

So, can i say that this is the same user? 90% the same, 50, 40... what percentage (if any)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each ISP is given a range of IP addresses, so it could either be different individuals or the same individual who has connected and disconnected a few times.

If you have a home network or a corporate network, devices are usually assigned "internal" IP addresses by a Network Address Translator (NAT) located within your router or modem. The NAT hides the internal IP addresses from websites, making the entire home network appear to outside computers to have a single, "external" IP address. In that case, you will only see the external IP address assigned to your home. Other network configurations, such as proxies, can also cause the IP address received by Google to differ from the actual IP address of your computer. [Summarized from Google support]